# VB.NET relative path connection string

Tags: vb.net, path, connection-string, relative-path

I need to make this connection string into a relative path so I can move my program from PC to PC without having to change the connection string every time. This is what I have in VB.NET:

```
 con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Newfolder\PizzaEmporium.mdf"";Integrated Security = True;Connect Timeout=30"
```

I get kind of lost on some of the examples from the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Path As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory

Dim con As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=" & Path &
  "\PizzaEmporium.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
```

Comment: Strings concatenation should use the" &" to concate, just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Get the path of the current directory with:

```
 Dim path As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory
```